# Do most shared hosts handle gzipped files?

Tags: javascript, compression, gzip

I get them theoretically, but I'm grappling with gzipping files in practice. How should I go about gzip compressing my files, and what needs to be done in order to use them on a shared host?

Would the following work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} .*gzip.*
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.js$ /$1.js.gz [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.css$ /$1.css.gz [L]
AddEncoding x-gzip text.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to have trouble with the MIME type of the decompressed content still being `application/gzip-compressed` rather than `text/css` or `text/javascript`.

What is your purpose in doing this? If you just want to cut down on network transfers, you should do that using `mod_deflate`, eg.:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript
```

and let Apache worry about compressing the transfers themselves on the fly. Otherwise browsers that can't negotiate gzip will be stuck.

I would hope a decent shared host would have already set compression for you. Use an [online tool](http://www.dnsqueries.com/en/check_http_gzip.php) to check whether your stylesheets are being served compressed.

Comment: Is this on by default, or do I have to add that somewhere specific, like in the php.ini file?

Comment: It goes in `httpd.conf`, `.htaccess` or wherever else you put Apache config. It's not on by default but I would expect shared hosts to enable it in their setups.