# mod_deflate or mod_gzip, which should be used?

Tags: apache, compression, http-compression

`mod_deflate` or `mod_gzip`, which should be used?

I read `mod_gzip` on better explained but want to know extra about `mod_deflate`.

Comment: What do you mean by mod_deflate and GZIP? Do you mean the Apache modules mod_deflate and mod_gzip?

Comment: yes (Apache modules mod_deflate and mod_gzip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read "[Compressing Web Content with mod_gzip and mod_deflate](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6802)" by Stephen Pierzchala.

From a pragmatic point of view, I suggest `mod_deflate` because it is easy to configure, [well documented](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html), and actively maintained. Also, a precompiled version of `mod_deflate` is more than likely available for your server. Apache may even come with `mod_deflate`, as is the case with the Windows installer and `apache2.2-bin` Debian package.

Answer (score 0):

While looking for mod_deflate, I ended up reading [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210517105433/https://www.geekride.com/apache-enable-mod_deflate-mod_gzip-module-compression-site-optimise/) article, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2682246/914874) answer. For me, it boils down to add

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/css
```

on my .htaccess and that is it.